# IllegalArgumentException in ByteBuffer during websocket send

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I have a fairly complex websocket based application running on an up to date Tomcat 8 server.

At fairly random intervals I get this exception, **simultaneously on all connected users.**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:275)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.PerMessageDeflate.sendMessagePart(PerMessageDeflate.java:377)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:284)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:258)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialBytes(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:161)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendBinary(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.sendBinaryMessage(StandardWebSocketSession.java:202)
at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.sendMessage(AbstractWebSocketSession.java:105)
at org.infpls.royale.server.game.session.RoyaleSession.sendImmiediate(RoyaleSession.java:69)
at org.infpls.royale.server.game.session.SessionThread.run(SessionThread.java:46)
```

After this exception is thrown, the web socket is left in a PARTIAL_WRITING state and disconnects on the next write attempt.

I've seen it happen 15 minutes after starting Tomcat and I've seen it happen after idling on the server for 8 hours. I cannot find any correlation to what users are doing on the server and when this exception is thrown.

The problem seems to be happening fairly deep into Spring/Java NIO code and I am not sure how to debug this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I took a shot in the dark after reading some slightly related issues from other people and instead of passing the bytebuffer off to the client threads to send it, I made full copies of the byte buffer for each thread that would send it.

I also switched from using the websocket.sendBinary(ByteBuffer bb) to using websocket.sendBinary(byte[] bb) instead.

That seems to have done the trick as I have not seen this bug happen again while running the server in production mode with pretty heavy load for 12 hours. If i find further information about this I will update it here.